# How to chain a dag to the first item of the next group, instead of last

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have code like this:

```
start >>
[
    task1,
    task2
]
>> task3
>> group1
>> task4
>> end
```

`task3` is chaining itself to the last `task` of `group1`.  Why is this?
I need `group1` to have upstream dependencies on `start`, `task1`, `task2`, and `task3`.  Currently, the `tasks` inside `group1` immediately kicks off as soon as the `DAG` is triggered.

The dag rendered. (do not want) is the result in airflow; (want) is what I need.

[image]

Comment: Consider aligning your task_id with task variable name and take a new screenshot so people could understand your question better

Comment: @511234 Figured it out... I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently `TaskGroup` task and `@task_group` decorators don't mean the same thing.  Originally, I had:

```
from airflow.decorators import task_group

@task_group
def group1():
    return sub_task1() >> sub_task2() >> sub_task3() >> sub_task4()
```

What I needed was:

```
def group1():
    # no decorator

with TaskGroup(group_id="group1") as group1_():
    group1()
```

Then I referenced the task as per usual:

```
start >>
[
    task1,
    task2
]
>> task3
>> group1_()
>> task4
>> end
```

I don't really understand the difference between the two, TBH.  But wrapping the func under a `with` clause instead of using the `@task_group` results in the expected behaviour.